# Provable data possession (PDP) VS Merkle tree

Tags: integrity, hash-tree, remote-data-checking

In the paper [Provable Data Possession at Untrusted Stores](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dawnsong/papers/p598-ateniese), there is a mechanism that allows a client to efficiently check if the server still has the client's data. They define two constraints for their system: server-side data access and communication complexity.

Also, they state that a scheme based on just Merkle tree cannot be secure (so they don't talk about the complexity here). They have cited a paper but cannot find any explanation for that.

**Question**: Why cannot we design a PDP using just a Merkle tree?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that like with the naive variant of simply asking for the hash of the data, the server can just throw away the data and store the hashes and still answer queries. It is important for such schemes that a query requires the server to use sufficient randomness together with the data in the computation of the answers. Then precomputing the potential answers will require too much storage and it is then actually less costly to keep the data itself.

Comment: thanks for the answer. We can build a Merkle tree on top of data blocks (so the leaf nodes are data blocks). In this case, the client can send random challenges, as it does in PDP, and the server provides proofs that include the blocks and their related paths in the tree.

Comment: Yes sure. But then you will have to maintain a potentially large state at the client right? This is what PDP wants to avoid.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but why do you think that the client needs to maintain a large state. Everything except the root of the tree is outsourced ot the server. Am I missing something?

Comment: How does a fixed root work together with random challenges? Wouldnt you need to locally compute and store a root per challenge before outsourcing?

Comment: the tree is built on top of data blocks. then the random challenges specify the indices of leaf nodes (or data blocks). Every time a set of challenges is sent to the server, it proves that the challenged blocks are in the tree. As you know, this requires sending the challenged blocks and some sibling nodes to the client.

Comment: Why isnt it easy to cheat? Server just stores the hashes of the authentication paths and throws away the data?

Comment: I think, in order for a server to prove that block B_i is in the tree, it has to send the path and B_i. I think this is what a proof in the Merkle tree contains. I admit that this is not efficient (in terms of communication), but it seems to be secure.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the goal of PDP to actually return the data you are probing. This will be highly inefficient for large data sets.

Comment: Yes that's right! but in the paper they said using a scheme based on Merkle tree does not guarantee data possession: see page 3 and table 1. They refer to the Markle tree based scheme as [20]-Wagner.

Comment: I'd say the question is how you define "data possession". They say that "We conclude that clients need to be able to verify that a server has retained file data without retrieving the data from the server and without having
the server access the entire file". Obviously if you want to check an entire file you need to retrieve every block + the path. So both things are violated. But it depends on the definition. Probably ask the authors and I do not know [20], so its hard to say.